# javascript delay output

Tags: ajax, django

I have written some code to display server's current date and time on browser every time user clicks the button . I have done this using ajax in django with the help of jquery. 
Now my, problem is I have to continously display the date and time once the button is clicked .
Some Sample code or utilities allowing such kind of delay will be helpful . 
Thanks in advance

The template is :

```
$(document).ready(function()  
 {  
          $("button").click(function()  
          {  
               $.ajax({  
                   type: "POST",  
                   url :"/showdate/",  
                   datatype: "json ",  
                   success : function(data){  
                             var s = data.currentdate;  
                             var sd = s  
                             $(sd).appendTo("div");  
                            }  
                });  

          });  
 });  

    <button type="button">Click Me</button>
    <div id="someid"></div>
```

The view function is :

```
def showdate(request):     
      now = datetime.datetime.now()  
      string_now = str(now)  
      return_dict = {'currentdate':string_now}  
      json = simplejson.dumps(return_dict)  
      return HttpResponse(json,mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make JS calculate and display the updated date every second. That way you avoid hitting your server with a new request all the time. Then make a call or example once every ten minutes or so to make sure the client and server is not out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

if you want update thing continuously than use `SetIterval` function available in the javascript. which call the function continuously.

check more about setinterval function : http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

sample code :

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
<input name="myClock" type="Text">
<script language=javascript>

self.setInterval('clock()', 50)

function clock() {
    time=new Date()
    document.myForm.myClock.value=time
}

</script>
</form>
```